# Generate multidimensional array in R

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

How can I generate a multidimensional array in R?

I have tried

```
courses <- 1:12

for (i in 1:300) {
  list[i] <- sample(courses, size=3, replace=FALSE)
}
```

but I get the warning

```
In list[i] <- sample(courses, size = 3, replace = FALSE) : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: Try `replicate(300, sample(courses, 3,replace=FALSE), simplify=FALSE)`

Comment: or if you really want to use a loop, note that 1. you should initiate the list `list <- list()` before the loop ; 2. you should use `[[` rather than `[`, because this is a list `list[[i]] <- sample...`

Comment: Wouldn't a ```data.frame``` do the job here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this via for loop.

Do like this..create/initiate a list samples

```
samples<-list()
```

Send data wrapping them in list

```
courses <- 1:12
for (i in 1:300) {
    samples[i] <- list(sample(courses, size=3, replace=FALSE))
}
```

Output :

```
head(samples)
[[1]]
[1] 9 2 5

[[2]]
[1]  4 10  5

[[3]]
[1]  7 10  8

[[4]]
[1] 7 5 3

[[5]]
[1] 3 9 8

[[6]]
[1]  9 11  3
```